# calling unicode character url in php

Tags: php

I am calling Api for sending SMS.

Here is which link I need to call

```
http://login.onlinebusinessbazaar.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=xxx&password=xxx1&msisdn=99245xxxxx&sid=xxxx&msg=આપનો સુપુત્ર/સુપુત્રી તા-28-07-2015ના રોજ શાળામાં ગેરહાજર છે&fl=0&dc=8&gwid=2
```

but when I m calling this link via `curl_exec($url)` or `header("location:".$url)`

it is automatically converted to

```
http://login.onlinebusinessbazaar.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=xxxx&password=xxx&msisdn=99245xxxxx&sid=xxxx&msg=%26%232694%3B%26%232730%3B%26%232728%3B%26%232763%3B%20%26%232744%3B%26%232753%3B%26%232730%3B%26%232753%3B%26%232724%3B%26%232765%3B%26%232736%3B/%26%232744%3B%26%232753%3B%26%232730%3B%26%232753%3B%26%232724%3B%26%232765%3B%26%232736%3B%26%232752%3B%20%26%232724%3B%26%232750%3B-28-07-2015%26%232728%3B%26%232750%3B%20%26%232736%3B%26%232763%3B%26%232716%3B%20%26%232742%3B%26%232750%3B%26%232739%3B%26%232750%3B%26%232734%3B%26%232750%3B%26%232690%3B%20%26%232711%3B%26%232759%3B%26%232736%3B%26%232745%3B%26%232750%3B%26%232716%3B%26%232736%3B%20%26%232715%3B%26%232759%3B&fl=0&dc=8&gwid=2
```

and I am getting respose A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (msg="આપ&#2728...").

if I am copying url

`(http://login.onlinebusinessbazaar.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=xxx&password=xxx1&msisdn=99245xxxxx&sid=xxxx&msg=આપનો સુપુત્ર/સુપુત્રી તા-28-07-2015ના રોજ શાળામાં ગેરહાજર છે&fl=0&dc=8&gwid=2)`

to browser it is working fine. thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `urlencode($url)` to encode the URL before calling `curl_exec()`.

Comment: Nope sir it is giving parameter missing error if i do url encode and if i just copy url without encode to broswer its working

Comment: Thank you sir i was calling urlencode on whole url .. now after calling it on only unicode fields its working !! :)